# Trouble finding the limits of integration for polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Use polar coordinates to evaluate $\iint_D x \, dA $, where D is the region inside the circle $x^2 +(y-1)^2 = 1$ but outside the circle $x^2 +y^2 = 1$ as shown below.

[image: region D]

Hi all, i'm stuck on finding the limits of integration for this particular question. The question states to use polar coordinates so what i've got was the following

$\pi/6 \le \theta \le {5\pi}/6$ and $1 \le r \le ??$

The upper limit of $r$ that i've gotten was something like $\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{1-r^2cos^2\theta}}$ which doesn't seem right.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to get the upper limit of r? Thanks in advance

Comment: The upper limit of $r$ shouldn't depend on $r$.

Comment: Let $x=rcos(\theta)$ and $y=rsin(\theta)+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Substitute the usual rectangular-to-polar transformation rules $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$, in the equation
$$x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 1$$
defining the upper circle.

Answer (score 0):

The range of $r$ is $1\le r\le 2\sin\theta$